# How to force a regression through the origin R

Tags: r, csv, regression

I am using R to do some multiple regression. I know that if you input for instance 
**reg <- lm(y~ 0 + x1+ x2, data)** you will force the regression model through the origin.

My problem is that i have alot of independant variables(+/-100) and R does not seem to read all of them if i input it this way

```
  lm(y~ 0 + x1 + x2 + ... + x100, data)
```

The code use is as follows:

```
[1] data <- read.csv("Test.csv")
[2] reg <- lm(data)
[3] summary(reg)
```

What do i need to put in line 2 so that i can force the model through the origin?
**reg <- lm(0 + data)** does not work.

Comment: Maybe provide some example data and the answer you want.

Comment: Put them in a dataframe or matrix and then do `lm(y ~ 0 + ., data)`.

Comment: lm(y ~ 0 + ., data) works, thanks.

Comment: @Thomas or OP: one of you could post as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your variables in a dataframe and use `.`:

```
lm(y ~ 0 + ., data)
```

See [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/formula.html):

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see [terms.formula](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/terms.formula.html). In the context of update.formula, only, it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’.